# Making end=" " and sep=" " take variables

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This is what I want it to be:

```
title = ['12', 'Years', 'a', 'Slave']

def join(x,y):
   for x in title:
    print(x,sep="y",end="")

join(title,-*-)
```

But I want it to see y as what is assigned to it not just as y

```
join(title,"-*-")
12-*-Years-*-a-*-Slave
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign "-*-" to y, you can just do `print(y.join(title))`

```
>>> title = ['12', 'Years', 'a', 'Slave']
>>> y = '-*-'
>>> y.join(title)
'12-*-Years-*-a-*-Slave'
```

That is a str method, try `help(str.join)` - you don't need to define your own function.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quote from the `sep` argument value. The argument to the print should be multiple argument to make `sep` take effect. You can use `*` operator that turns the list into arguments. (See [Unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists))

```
>>> def join(title, sep):
...     print(*title, sep=sep)
...
>>> title = ['12', 'Years', 'a', 'Slave']
>>> join(title, '-*-')
12-*-Years-*-a-*-Slave
```

Comment: What does adding the "*" before "title" do?

Comment: @Montop20, Please follow the link in the answer. There's a kind explanation about what it does.